# How to minimize time conversion html to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

Hello I am using the following code in order to convert html to NSAttributtedString. My problem is that it takes long time the first time that I executed it:

```
var html = "<b>Whatever...</b>"    
var attributedText = try! NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: html.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
```

When I perform the conversion for the first time, it takes long time executing. The followed executions takes less time. There is any way to decrease this long first execution?
I thought about execute this code in background at the begining of my app execution but I want to know if there is other smart solution or library the I should import.

Comment: From your potential solution, note that from the doc: `The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType).`

Comment: It's a great question ƒernando .  We found there is NO WAY to make it faster.  What I do is just do it on another thread as you say.  Of course this causes lots of UX problems.  You have to cache it of course then  :/

Comment: note that in some cases this library may help https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftRichString associated article https://medium.com/breakfastcode/attributed-strings-in-swift-6d4b37db59a5

Comment: Hello @ƒernando Valle, have you found any solution to this problem... I am facing same problem.

Comment: Hello @MehulThakkar I did not find any solution for reduce the time but I "Hacked" this adding a fake html loading in my appdelegate class. I will post it  as an answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: ok thanks  @ƒernando Valle for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any way to reduce the conversion time. But there is a way for "hack" the time of load.

Seems that the process of conversion take a long time the first time it is called but less in the next calls. In this way, I solved the problem loading a piece of "html spam" in my AppDelegate. So, the user will not get noticed the slow loading during the use of the application.

**AppDelegate:**

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    super.application(application, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    try! NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: "<a>asdasd</a>".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue
        ],
        documentAttributes: nil)

    return true
}
```

In the ViewControllers you can call as normal:

```
var html = "<b>Whatever...</b>"    
var attributedText = try! NSMutableAttributedString(
    data: html.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
    options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
    documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: @Mehul Thakkar try it and tell me ;)

Comment: I tried this, it minimized somewhat time, but not much smooth still

Comment: for me it didn't help :(

Answer (score -1):

> use "String.Encoding.utf8" instead of "String.Encoding.unicode"
>   this might reduce your conversion time

```
var html = "<bold>Wow!</bold> Now <em>iOS</em> can create <h3>NSAttributedString</h3> from HTMLs!"

let attributedOptions: [String: Any] = [
                    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                ]

var attrString = try! NSAttributedString(data: html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: Ya i read your question. you are facing some delay in HTML comversion i think its because you are using "String.Encoding.unicode" instead of 
"String.Encoding.utf8" I thinnk it will reduce your conversion

Comment: @MilapKundalia Worth pointing out that difference in your answer then, if you think that's the issue.

Comment: Sry, I didnt noticed the change. seems that this solution does minimize a little the conversion time, thanks.

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work properly, I do not if something is saved in cache but today (maybe because restart) it does not minimize the time.

Comment: This one is wrong, there's no time difference here.